# Apostol Mathematical Analysis Theorem 6.14 Functions of Bounded Variation Missing Proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, bounded-variation

[image: Apostol Proof]

In the above proof, next to the area with the blue line, Apostol assumes that the arbitrary point $x$ that he is trying to prove that $V(x)-V(c)<\epsilon$ for is less than $x_1$ thus he can say "Adding more points to $P$ can only increase the sum". But if say $x>x_1$ we cannot use the inequality $$V_f(c,b)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\sum^n_{k=2}|\triangle f_k|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}+V_f(x_1,b).$$ Can someone clarify whether Apostol is wrong or if there is something I am missing here.

Comment: What's the definition of $V_f(\cdot,\cdot)$? I'm guessing a measure of the variation of $f$. Also, what does $\Delta f_k$ denote?

Comment: $V_f(a,b)=sup\{\sum(|\triangle f_k|): \text{for all partitions of} [a,b]\}$ and $\triangle f_k = f(x_k)-f(x_k-1)$ where $x_0,..,x_n$ is a partition of the closed interval $f$ is on. $V_f(a,b)$ is also called total variation.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just an instance of the triangle inequality.

That is, suppose we add a point between $x_j$ and $x_{j+1}$, call it $p$, then  $\sum_{k=0}^n|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|\leq\sum_{k=0,k\neq j}^n|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|+|f(p)-f(x_j)|+|f(x_j)-f(p)|.$

Comment: @R.Steven but how can you then say that $$\sum^n_{k=1}|\triangle f_k|\le V_f(p,b).$$. Also I think your index should be $j+1$.

Comment: You are correct, I should have had my my sum where $ k=1,...,n$. From there, we are now assuming that $ a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b $, and $ x_1-x_0<\delta$. With this in mind: $ \sum_{k=2}^n|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|$ which is a sum over a partition of $[x_1,b]$ and so by definition of $V_f(x_1,b) $ as the supremum over all such sums gives the inequality.

Comment: +1 for noticing an error (minor though) in an otherwise excellent book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's minor issue here which can be fixed easily. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta'>0$ be such that $$|f(x) - f(c) |<\frac{\epsilon} {2}$$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta '$. And let $$P=\{c=x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n=b\}$$ be a partition of $[c, b] $ such that $$V_f(c, b) - \frac{\epsilon} {2}<\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$$ Let $\delta=\min(\delta', x_1-x_0)$ and consider point $x$ such that $0<x-c<\delta$. Also let $$P'=P\cup\{x\} =\{c=x'_0,x=x'_1,x'_2,\dots,x'_m=b\}$$ and continue the argument of Apostol with above partition.

Comment: Great ! I am just wondering here but would you consider Apostol's argument to be "wrong".

Comment: @Nameless: one should not mind such minor issues. I love Apostol's books which are far superior than most American texts (including Rudin's).

Answer (score 0):

$x_1$ is essentially an arbitrary point. If we wanted to test another point $x \in B_\delta(c)$ with $x>x_1$, then add it to the partition and run the same argument with $x$ replacing $x_1$.

Edit: To address the question of testing another point in the partition (not $x_1$), just add enough points so that you have $p \in B_\delta(c)$. Nothing in the argument hinges on $x_1$ being the first point in the partition after $c$.

Comment: I don't think $x_1$ is arbitrary since it exists from partition $x_0,...,x_n$.

Comment: But, as Apostol wrote, adding more points to the partition will only make the sum $\sum_k \lvert \Delta f_k \rvert$ grow larger and so the desired inequality will still hold for the refined partition.

Comment: Yes, but if we add the point after $x_1$ how can you make the claim that $$\sum^n_{k=1}|\triangle f_k|\le V_f(x,b).$$ where this sum doesn't go over the point $x$ that was added between say $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: The sum does go over that point. If you add a point $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$, then leave $x_0,x_1$ alone, let $x_2=x$, set $x_3=x_2$ and continue to increase the index on each $x_j$ by one. Then, you have $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \cdot$ and it will have all the properties you want.

Comment: I think what I am trying to say is what if the point we want to add say it is called $p$ is equal to say $x_2=p$. Apostol assumes we can add the point $p$ before the $x_1$ hence says it doesn't matter if you add it you can just assume that it is $x_1$ since adding any point before $x_1$ doesn't change the argument.(Here $p$ is the arbitrary point that I called $x$ in the post).

Comment: If our point is $x_2$, then just add enough points so that $x_2 \in B_\delta(c)$. Relabel the points if necessary.